# CXF: generated WSDL vs. original WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, wsdl, cxf

I have a question regarding WSDLs generated from CXF. From what I understood is that the WSDL that’s published by CXF is generated from JAX-WS/JAXB.

I have a WSDL file with the following content:

```
...
<xsd:complexType name="Scenario" mixed="true">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Description" type="xsd:anyURI" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:any namespace="##other" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
</xsd:complexType>
...
```

After I generated my classes and deployed the service I checked the interface in my browser (with ?wsdl). Much to my surprise it looked considerably different: a "choice" has been added, processContents is changed, etc.

```
...
<xsd:complexType mixed="true" name="Scenario">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:element name="Description" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
        <xsd:choice>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="skip"/>
</xsd:complexType>
...
```

I am especially interested in this additional choice that’s been added?

Is it maybe because of the "xsd:any"?

Comment: I had just same issue :/ we dont event have "any" in xsd and its generating choice from mixed=true. I think its maybe CXF bug.